Non existent path or file when reading a file in a network shared drive, in Oracle DB 21c XE?
I have a network public drive with EVERYONE access to read and write, which is my PC running windows 10. My oracle instance is running on my laptop which is windows 11 and I have mounted the network drive as Z drive in my laptop and I am able to access and edit files inside the drive.
The file is in Z:/test.txt
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY NETTEST AS 'Z:'; - Used to create the directory object and granted read and write permissions aswell.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    f1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    s  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    f1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('NETTEST', 'test.txt', 'r');
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f1, s);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(s);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(f1);
END;
/

Above PLSQL code was used to read the data inside the text file. But I keep getting this error.
Error report -
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at line 5
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation%s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.

Help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Be aware that on Windows there is a known issue with version 21 where drives that are not that of the drive that the database is installed on may incorrectly report errors with UTL_FILE, eg
SQL> create or replace directory tmp as 'x:\tmp';  -- valid on OS

Directory created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      f1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  3      s  VARCHAR2(32767);
  4  BEGIN
  5      f1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TMP', 'test.txt', 'w');
  6              UTL_FILE.put_LINE(f1, 'xxxxx');
  7      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(f1);
  8  END;
  9  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL> create or replace directory tmp as 'c:\tmp';  -- also valid

Directory created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      f1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  3      s  VARCHAR2(32767);
  4  BEGIN
  5      f1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TMP', 'test.txt', 'w');
  6              UTL_FILE.put_LINE(f1, 'xxxxx');
  7      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(f1);
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The "workaround" is to relocate the file :-(

Add a backslash at the end of the directory string. Your code works for me with either a backslash or a forward slash, but it might be safer to use a backslash since that's what windows typically uses.
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY NETTEST AS 'Z:\';

